# Display current page in rails haml template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I know this is crazy simple, but I can't figure it out even after reviewing the HAML docs. How do you return the current page/path (current_page). I want to add a simple share on Twitter link to my app that contains the current path.

```
%a.twitter{href: "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=CURRENT_PAGE_?????&text=#{blah}"} Tweet
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `request.url`. It's available in controllers and views.